# Recurring contribution cancelled in CiviCRM but still active in PayPal

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, recurring-contributions

I cancelled a monthly recurring contribution in the back end, and the status now shows "cancelled" but in PayPal (more than 24 hours later) it's still Active.
My understanding was the cancellation should have propagated to PayPal, yes?

CiviCRM 4.6.18
Joomla 3.5.1

Comment: That depends on whether you have PayPal Standard, Express, or Pro.  Could you please edit your question to indicate which?

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I don't recall reading that CiviCRM tells Paypal to cancel the recurring charge. I think you have to do that in Paypal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jenni ... if the "Change billing details" function does just that in PayPal, why would the "Cancel" function not cancel it in PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

Although the code has a cancel payment function which calls the PayPal service, there's also a comment saying

```
// since subscription methods like cancelSubscription or updateBilling is not yet implemented / supported by standard or express.
```

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php#L637

Please can you provide more info on your PayPal installation?